# Custom UITableViewCell using UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle & adjusting UILabel frame width

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel, autolayout

My issue: I need to display text and detail text along with a `UISwitch` in a table view cell and not have text overlap switch. Started by using `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle` and adding the switch using `[cell.contentView addSubview:mySwitch]`. This all worked fine, but when I began adding some of my real data, some of the text is really long and because of the width of the default `textLabel`, it overlapped with the switch. If I shrink the switch, it gets too small to reasonably tap. And I can't adjust the label frame.

I tried building custom labels and adding to the cell, but what I lost was the built in auto layout of the text (dynamically moving the textLabel around based on its length) built into the `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle`.

Closest I've gotten is using a custom table view cell in which I override `layoutSubviews` and shrink the width a tad. Then in cellforrow I use that custom cell and `initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle`. Problem now is some text isn't wrapping. It's strange, if the text would fit on one line (pre width adjustment), after adjusting the height, its not showing that last word on a second line, its just skinnier, but still one line. Everything else seems to be fine, if something has enough text for 2 lines, it's 2 lines. I tried `sizewithfont:constrainedtosize:linebreakmode:` and I can get the label to change its height, but its not adjusting its position to be higher in the cell.

How can I get the label to know all the text isn't on the one line (with the new width) and to wrap? Trying to avoid building an entire cell and logic for text lengths, height, y position, etc.

Comment: I'm sorry but I haven't understood your question. Is it that you don't want to create a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass and want to somehow alter the auto layout behaviour of one of the default styles? Or is it that you want the `UILabel` to adjust the number of lines automatically (`yourLabel.numberOfLines = 0`)?

Comment: sorry for any confusion, i was trying to avoid coding a bunch of custom logic (if text is 2 lines, height is this, y position this) and it seemed like i could just use what was built in by default. but for some reason the default textLabel width leaves almost no room for anything on the right side (switch in my case). I have a custom UITableViewCell subclass, but adjusting the width in layoutSubviews seems to not display the text correctly in some cases. its only if my manual width adjustment forces the text to another line. if it was going to be on 2 lines anyway, its fine

Comment: I think the only way this will work is to build a fully auto-layout enabled custom cell (no adjusting frames manually). The building of the cell with `UILabels` and a `UISwitch` with auto-layout should be OK but the tricky part will be calculating the height of the cell based on the content in your model (rather than referencing the cell). You'll be calling `sizeToFit` in the subclass but I'm not sure how you'll get the height ahead of time. Perhaps someone else knows or StackOverflow has an answer. Also see here for a solution:http://www.cimgf.com/2009/09/23/uitableviewcell-dynamic-height/

Comment: thanks! that was my worry. reason i was avoiding that is that i have a storyboard scene with things already set with auto layout (i have a bunch of uitableviews on one screen) and i feared adding a prototype would throw it off. can you add a cell and have it be on its own on the that storyboard, without it being in a controller?

Comment: Adding a prototype cell inside a tableview in a Storyboard should not affect the auto-layout of anything else in that scene. But, as always, take a backup / commit before making major changes. Accidents do happen after all.

Comment: ok cool, yep, will definitely commit beforehand, thanks!